# Docker Port Mappings and Hostnames

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This question is related to understanding how docker deals with a container's hostnames and ports.

Let's say I have two services that are running in a different docker container and exposing port 80 from the container to port 8081 (service1) and port 8082 (service2):

```
service1: 8081:80
service2: 8082:80
```

Now it is clear to me that from a host perspective, I can access these services by using the exposed ports (http://localhost:8081 and http://localhost:8082). But what if I want to access my services by using the containers like http://container1 and http://container2? What I have to do to realize this scenario meaning:

- how might the port be forwarded?
- and how do I know the exact hostname to resolve the container's hostnames from the docker host machine?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: deploy a third container with nginx as proxy , that will serve those ports as http://container1 ,  and http://container2

Answer (score 4):

As Ijaz Ahmad Khan said. You have to use another container inside that network as proxy eg nginx.

If you are exposing ports from `docker-compose` to host machine ( your pc ) it's only visible as localhost domain with specific port as you mention. If you run `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  service1:
    image: something
    name: service1_name
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
  service2:
    image: something
    name: service2_name
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
```

Docker-compose will create default network named by folder in witch is `docker-compose.yml` with suffix `_default`. In this network all  container can see each other. `expose` command is used for containers inside this network (so they can see each other and communicate), `port` is used for publishing to host-machine (your pc).
This mean:

service1 is visible on your machine as `http://localhost:8081` for others containers in the network as `service1:80`.

service2 is visible on your machine as `http://localhost:8082` for others containers in the network as `service2:80`.

See that specified container name doesn't have effect on service network address. To test that containers are only visible inside the network try to ping them from another container

```
docker run --rm --network=your_folder_name_default debian ping service1
```

To check in which network your containers are running you could use `inspect`

```
docker inspect service1_name
```

Now you have to use the container name

Comment: do you have an example how to use an nginx proxy container? Thx.